# how to flip normal direction in blender

Tags: normals

I  am following a blender beginner tutorial by blenderguru and he is me how to make a doughnut.so we wanted to make sprinkles and he said we needed to change normal direction to face inwards. in his blender(which is an older version), you can do that by selecting the 'shading/uv's' section in the tool bar. however, the new version doesn't have it there. Can someone tell me where it might have been moved?

anyhelp will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to say which blender version, rather than "the new version". It is there in Blender 2.79 in the same place you mentioned under Shading/UV tab. The tab will show up only when you have your doughnut in edit mode.

Answer (score 4):

**Flip Normals**

*(re the title "How to flip normals"*)

In edit mode, select the faces you wish to flip normals and

*`Mesh > Normals > Flip Normals`*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select all vertices in Edit Mode and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>. That should calculate the normals inside.