# Blender's mesh problem with shaders

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I started working on a body today and made a body and a hand. I did them both separately. The problem comes when I try to connect them. There's a really weird, sharp shadow coming when I make a face between them. It's not a flipped normal. I already tried flipping it but it's still the same deal. If you'd look closely the two vertices connecting are really sharp.

Any help would be really appriciated!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to flip normal direction in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105125/how-to-flip-normal-direction-in-blender)

Comment: yeah but when i flip the normals the others are changing aswell

Comment: Have you tried to ***recalculate** the normals*?

Comment: Close the entire loop first, then try to *remove doubles* and *recalculate the normals*...

Comment: Please give your questions descriptive titles. The current one does not convey any information about the question at all

Comment: sorry about that Martin .. its my first time posting a question and english isn't really my strong side... Ill change the title. I got the answer though! How can i mark Brockmann's comment as the answer?

Comment: If you create new faces, sometimes you have to click on shade smooth (object menu in object mode) again, to smooth them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)